# sum of the first $n$ terms of a quadratic sequence

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(2i+3)^2=\frac{(n+1)(4n^2+20n+27)}{3}$$

Hey! :) I need help with this problem, I'm kinda silly and I've got a problem with this, I don't even know how to start. If you guys can help me that would be amazing. I'm in my first year of university and I don't know how to do it. :(

Comment: Do you know what induction is?

Comment: You know the formula for the sum of the first n numbers? For the first n squares? Can you expand the summation and use the linearity of the sum operator?

Comment: ( nb: my suggestion goes in a different direction than the comment of Dasherman )

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess that those are what we need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can prove this either with so-called [Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) or just calculate the expression on the LHS. I will try show the second approach here.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(2i+3)^2=\sum_{i=0}^n(4i^2+12i+9)=4\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^ni^2}_{S_1}+12\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^ni}_{S_2}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^n9}_{S_3}$$
So, now we can notice that $S_1$ is just the [sum of the squares of first $n$ natural numbers](https://www.ask-math.com/sum-of-squares-of-n-natural-numbers.html) and $S_2$ is an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). Using the known formulas (which you can find the proofs by clicking on the hyperlinks above), we obtain that
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(2i+3)^2=4\sum_{i=0}^ni^2+12\sum_{i=0}^ni+\sum_{i=0}^n9=4\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+12\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+9(n+1)=\frac{(n+1)(4n^2+20n+27)}{3}$$ as desired.

Comment: FYI: This seems like you answered the question in the current body of the question, and then changed it later to where the terms are squared (i.e., $(2i+3)^2$ instead of $2i+3$), but didn't change the links to the formulas.

Comment: I just edited the OP's question to match your answer (and the original image).

Comment: @BrianTung Yeah it seems I omitted the square $^2$ when replacing the screenshot in the OP with a corresponding LaTeX. Also, I omitted the word "squares" in the link. Thanks. Now fixed.